# To check if an image file exists and load another default file if not

Tags: reactjs

In my developing with React, I encounter this problem:

I retrieve certain data from a remote API with relevant information to describe a book: http://api.rsywx.com/book/randomBook/1. This will return a JSON string:

```
{"status":200,"out":[{"bookid":"00637","title":"\u4e2d\u56fd\u53e4\u4ee3\u601d\u60f3\u53f2","author":"\u6768\u8363\u56fd","region":"\u4e2d\u56fd\u5927\u9646","purchdate":"1973-09-13"}]}
```

Out of this return, I populate a `state` object and to display that book in the page.

One thing is that I need to display a book cover associated with that book. I don't have covers for all my books stored in (and thus randomly returned from) the API.

If a cover image is there, I can safely display that image via:

```
    <img
        className="ls-l"
        src={this.state.cover}
    .../>
```

`cover` is populated from `bookid`.

But if not, I must display a `default.jpg` as a fallback.

So basically I need to check if `this.state.cover` file exists.

Any input will be much appreciated.

**Update**

Thanks for all's input below.

I think it may be that I did not make my self clear.

No matter whether the image file exists in my server side, `this.state.cover` will be populated from `bookid`, i.e, in the form of "http://myserver/img/12345.jpg", where `12345` is the `bookid`.

The real situaion is that file `12345.jpg` exisits, but `54321.jpg` is not.

So before I display the image in my `<img>` tag, I have to replace `54321.jpg` to `default.jpg`. I think this is a question related to file manupilation.

The below methods are assuming `cover` field is not set, which is not the case in my code.

Nevertheless, thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Two different ways:

`let {cover = "fallback.jpg"} = this.state;`

Or

`src={this.state.cover || "fallback.jpg"}`

Or you use the [monadic](http://jrsinclair.com/articles/2016/marvellously-mysterious-javascript-maybe-monad/) goodness of functional programming to get rid of the null checks.

Comment: Very nice first option! And great article by the way!

Comment: Thanks Dan, do check out the other articles on the same site, they helped me a lot to learn fp which is aimed at handling situation exactly as this one with elegance. Another resource interested readers may find helpful is [this](https://github.com/MostlyAdequate/mostly-adequate-guide).

Answer (score 1):

```
         fetch(url,{}) 
              .then( (response)=> response.json())
                   .then((book) => this.setState({
                             picture: book.picture || defaultCover.jpg   
                                }))
```

You can go with the usual `||`  operator here. This would work fine. But be sure of the ordering. In `pic1 || pic2` pic1 is checked first. If it is undefined, it goes for pic2.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional operator to check if cover property exists or not. Use something like this,

```
const defaultImage = "some-url";
<img
        className="ls-l"
        src={this.state.cover ? this.state.cover : defaultImage}
    .../>
```